# git msys2 git-lfs - cannot install git-lfs

Tags: git, msys2

I uninstalled `git` and [all its dependencies](https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html)

```
pacman -Rcns git
```

Then a system upgrade

```
pacman -Syu
```

I then installed `git-lfs` which re-installed git

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-git-lfs
```

https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-git-lfs?repo=mingw64

But I get

```
$ git status
git-lfs filter-process: line 1: git-lfs: command not found
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Check which packages with **git** in name are installed:

```
$ pacman -Q | grep git
git 2.37.1-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git 10.0.0.r54.gb4116e310-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-git-lfs 3.2.0-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git 10.0.0.r54.gb4116e310-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git 10.0.0.r54.gb4116e310-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git 10.0.0.r54.gb4116e310-1
```

**QUESTION**
Why won't `git-lfs` install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the steps

In addition to steps in question above,

Install `git-lfs`

```
$ /mingw64/bin/git-lfs install
Git LFS initialized.
```

Now problem is that `mingw64/bin` is not in the path; I choose to copy `git-lfs` to where `git` is

```
cp /mingw64/bin/git-lfs /usr/bin/
```

Then do final step

```
$ git lfs install
Updated Git hooks.
Git LFS initialized.
```

Comment: I actually needed to do this in order for LFS to be useable from other programs: `ln /mingw64/bin/git-lfs /usr/bin/git-lfs.exe`